# How to install ARM translation on an Android emulator inside Docker

Tags: android, docker, qemu, arm, android-x86

I want to install an ARM .apk onto a x86 Android emulator. It already works with libhoudini and Genymotion. Now I want to use libhoudini with [docker-android](https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android).

I already tried the solution from [How to flash zip on Genymotion programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625746/how-to-flash-zip-on-genymotion-programmatically) (extracting the shell script and pushing it via adb to the emulator inside Docker), but this didn't work either because unzip/zip is not supported.

What is the best way to run an ARM .apk on a x86 emulator inside Docker?